# How to execute several macros with one command?

Tags: macro

I have three macros that I have created separately over time. `a` performs a search and replace, `b` adds tags to every line and `c` appends text at the beginning and the end of the file.

I execute them like this:

`@a`

`:%norm! @b`

`@c`

How can I execute them in this order without starting each one separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a macros why not use another macro to execute the other three!

```
let @q = "@a:norm! @b\<cr>@c"
@q
```

Note: I am using `:let` to set the `q` register here, but you could just as easily record a macro with `q`, e.g. `qq@a:norm! @b^M@cq` (where `^M` is pressing <kbd>return</kbd>).

Answer (score 4):

You can execute all of them in a single normal command. For example:

```
:normal @a:%norm! @b^M@c
```

Note that `^M` is a literal carriage return, and is typed by pressing `<C-v><cr>`, *not* the literal text `^M`.